# AGM MAP binding issue

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

The goal is to draw circle in the map to define geofence rule and to update the form fields based on coordinates and radius of the circle.

I added radius_changed handling inside circlecomplete handle like this:

```
const _self = this;
const precision = 1000000;
// handle draging
google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'radius_changed', function () {
  _self.updateLocationData({
    latitude: Math.round(circle.getCenter().lat() * precision) / precision,
    longitude: Math.round(circle.getCenter().lng() * precision) / precision,
    radius: Math.round(circle.getRadius())
  });
});
```

It triggers updateLocationData method defined as:

```
updateLocationData(data: any) {
this.circleUpdateSource$.next(data);
```

}

That I am subscribed to in ngOnInit:

```
this.circleUpdateSource.subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.test = data.radius;
  this.rule = {
    radius: data.radius,
    lat: data.latitude,
    lng: data.longitude
  };
});
```

Everything works well except binding data in subscription to template. Console.log outputs immediately right when the event is triggered but the {{test}} or {{rule}} is updated ONLY after the cursor moves out from the circle or if I click in the map outside the circle. Any idea?

Comment: you used agm-map tag, but you are not using AGM. I recommend taking a look: angular-maps.com

Answer (score 0):

I have found the trick others may benefit! You need to call a tick manually to trigger the update in template!

```
this.appRef.tick();
```

In import:

```
ApplicationRef
```

In constructor:

```
private appRef: ApplicationRef
```